# FileManager-Actions: is it possible to launch an action in the current directory?

Tags: contextmenu, gnome, file-management, nautilus

I want to create a simple action, which would launch MS Visual Code from the Nautilus context menu in the currently opened folder.

The default parameter for working directory (`%d` - first base directory) makes it close: the App is launched in the parent directory.[image]

For example, if I execute the action from the `/mnt/sdb1/anaconda3/etc` path, MS VisualStudioCode is launched in the parent dir - `/mnt/sdb1/anaconda3/`.

I looked up the list of available parameters, but wasn't able to find the suitable one. Quite surprisingly for me, `%b` parameter (first basename) performed this action in the current dir (as I would want it to be performed), but it didn't work for the mounted drive. I cannot understand if this is kind of a bug, or there is a proper way to set up the action I need.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `%d` for `%f`

More information about it on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783292/what-do-the-various-percent-parameters-in-context-menu-actions-or-desktop-f).

Hope it helps!